# MVC Model property names with square brackets - is this possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, properties, http-post

When POSTing data to a third-party payment provider, I usually serialize an MVC model which represents the fields.  I have used this technique many times and has worked perfectly.

However now I am faced with this specification:
[image: http post parameters]

Note that the field names contain square brackets.  I can't work out how to include the full field name in my model properties, currently the model looks like this:

```
public string action { get; set; }
public string api_key { get; set; }
public string RetailerUniqueRef { get; set; }
public string InstallationID { get; set; }
public float Price { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public string Code { get; set; }
public float Deposit { get; set; }
public string SchemeCode { get; set; }
```

As you can see, the property names are only part of the field names.  If I add the square brackets like so:

```
public string identification[api_key] { get; set; }
```

This fails as the compiler quite rightly thinks it's an array.
How can I include the square brackets in the property names, or is there another way round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could use some form of attribute to mark up your property then use reflection to get the name. However in the example you have provided the `data` object is a `NameValueCollection` with the key being a string, meaning there is no need to do so or even use the property name.

I suspect that you will need to do something like this:-

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.ApiKey = "SomeRandomApiKeySetByTheProvider";
foo.Code = "ONIF6";

var data = new NameValueCollection();
data.Add("Identification[api_key]", foo.ApiKey);
...
data.Add("Finance[Code]", foo.Code);
```